# Installing IIS on windows server 2003, which files from SP2 CD are needed?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis

I'm trying to install IIS on Windows Server 2003 and in the Windows Components Wizard, it prompts me to "Insert Service Pack 2 CD-ROM".. I'm assuming this is the Windows Server 2003 installation CD, CD 2.  However when I try to put it in, it doesn't seem to recognize it..  In the D: drive, it is called CR0SCD2X_EN.  Do you folks have any ideas on how to fix this?  Thanks.

Edit: I entered in CD1 and seems like it gave it a kick start.  However, now it is complaining about where a convlog.exe file is. Doesn't seem to be in CD1 or CD2.  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's asking for the installation files for *Service Pack 2*, not CD 2. It's asking for what it needs - the versions of the files already on the system are at SP2, but the installation source files aren't there for whatever reason.

Once you do what you're talking about - essentially, forcing SP1 files (2003 R2 shipped with SP1 included) in place of SP2 - you'll end up with a mostly-working-but-partially-broken IIS installation, which won't install at least some security updates correctly.

I'd suggest you download and extract the SP2 installation files to somewhere accessible from this computer, then uninstall and reinstall IIS on the box with that location specified when it prompts for the SP2 "CD".

If not, after you've forced it through like this, a) reinstall SP2, and b) run Windows Update again.

**Edit:** One such breakage is this one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2009746

Comment: I still don't fully understand the installation files for Service Pack 2.  I only have the installation CDs 1 and 2 to Windows Server 2003 R2 Standard x64 with SP2 and they are both .iso, so it is unclear which files it needs.

Comment: The original OS disks ship with SP1 on them. Disk 1 is the only disk with actual Windows source files on it, so ignore disk 2 for the purposes of this discussion. When you need to add files, Windows assumes you're adding from CD (how quaint) and asks for the CD with the title of the software it needs. It doesn't matter you don't have an actual ISO or CD of the stuff, it just needs the expanded files from Service Pack 2 - which, unless you've slipstreamed it, will NOT be on the CD1 media (and NO chance it's on CD2). You're welcome not to take this advice, but the box will break at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Kinda weird, but with the help of [IIS forum](http://forums.iis.net/t/1162134.aspx), I was able to do this:
Run this command from command prompt:

```
esentutl /p c:\windows\Security\Database\Secedit.sdb
```

And installing IIS after that.  It works!

Comment: No, it's just patched over the original problem. You need to reapply SP2 + updates at a minimum - check the file versions in the InetSrv directory against a recent security update.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a slipstreamed CD, point the installer to it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem might have an utterly stupid solution:

If the "Files Needed" dialog is proposing the location `"C:\WINDOWS\INSTALLATION\I386\i386"`, try **deleting the last I386** (from the dialog's path):

With the current AWS EC2 Windows Server R2 image (*ami-26e3e7cd*) that's all is needed: it looks like some installer genius just typed the wrong location somewhere!

The prompt will come up for each missing file, so you'll have to do this several times.

Precisely these are the files for which I get a prompt when installing IIS (the Application Server role):

- convlog.exe
- iisback.vbs
- iis6.cab